# How is the number for a year read?

Tags: grammar-choice

In many texts, years are written in Roman or Arabic numerals like MMIV for 2004.

Should I read them cardinally or ordinally? Is there any evidence for the way to read?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is **ordinally**.

> Evenit anno Domini millesimo nongentesimo duodenonagesimo.
> Evenit anno Domini MCMLXXXVIII.
> Evenit anno Domini 1988.
> It happened in nineteen eighty-eight.

Literally:

> It happened in the one thousand nine hundred and eighty-eighth year of the Lord.

You can leave *Domini* out, of course – nobody is probably going to be confused whether you mean before or after Christ – but I would generally not leave *anno* out like you would in English.

If you *do* mean before Christ, you say *ante Christum natum* (e.g. *consul fuit anno sexagesimo tertio a. Chr. n.*). *Post Christum natum = p. Chr. n.* also exists. (In case you are wondering, this is a so-called dominant participle construction; it *seems* to say “before/after the born Christ,” but the actual meaning is, of course, “before/after the birth of Christ.”)